# Splitting words to rows in DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a DataFrame where one of the columns contains strings. I would like to split the strings by spaces and then transform the DataTable, so that it contains one word per row.

```
dat = pd.DataFrame(data = {'x' : [1,2],
                           'y' : ['Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet',
                                  'consectetur adipiscing elit']})
```

I would like to get DataFrame like below:

```
 x   y
 1   Lorem
 1   ipsum
 ...
 2   consectetur 
 2   adipiscing 
 ...
```

What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) for `list`s first and then [`numpy.repeat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) with [`numpy.concatenate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html) and last `DataFrame` constructor:

```
s = dat['y'].str.split()
a = np.repeat(dat['x'].values, s.str.len())
b = np.concatenate(s.values)

df = pd.DataFrame({'x':a,'y':b})
print (df)
   x            y
0  1        Lorem
1  1        ipsum
2  1        dolor
3  1          sit
4  1         amet
5  2  consectetur
6  2   adipiscing
7  2         elit
```

Answer (score 1):

str to `list` , then we using `stack`

```
dat.y=dat.y.str.split(' ')
dat.set_index('x').y.apply(pd.Series).stack().reset_index().\
        drop('level_1',1).rename(columns={0:'y'})
Out[484]: 
   x            y
0  1        Lorem
1  1        ipsum
2  1        dolor
3  1          sit
4  1         amet
5  2  consectetur
6  2   adipiscing
7  2         elit
```